# JSON schema: referencing a local child schema

Tags: node.js, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I want to reference a child schema in a parent json schema. Here is the child schema named child.json

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"title": "Child",
"description": "Child schema",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "name": {"type": "string"},
    "age": {"type": "integer"}
}}
```

and here is the parent schema named parent.json and all the two files are in the same folder. I want to refer to the child schema and i do like this:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"title": "Parent",
"description": "Parent schema",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
"allOf": [
    {
        "$ref": "file://child.json"
    }
],
"adresse": {"type": "string"}
}}
```

I've an error saying that the file child.json is not found. I've tested lot of tings but anyone is working. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: This might depend on the library you are using. Json-schema relies on ref value to be a valid URI. Have you tried with "child.json" or "file:child.json"? Which library are you using and how do you load the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution for my problem. Here is the solution
The context is that we always have two schemas: the parent and the child. The parent have to include the child schema in one of his properties like this par exemple:

```
"myChild": {
      "$ref": "child" //referencing to child schema
}
```

And in the child schema at the beginning of him, you have to put an id on it like this

```
{
    "id": "child", //important thing not to forget
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"
    //other codes goes here
}
```

Now for the validation with jaySchema you will do like this

```
var js = new JaySchema();
var childSchema = require('./child.json');
var parentSchema = require('./parent.json');

//other codes goes here
js.register(childSchema); //important thing not to forget
js.validate(req.body, schema, function(err) {
    if (err) //your codes for err
});
```

And it's all. :-D
This is my solution but it's not the best and i hope that it will help. Thanks to all for your answers

Answer (score 1):

`$ref` values can be URI References - they don't need to be absolute URIs.  So here, you should just be able to use:

```
{"$ref": "child.json"}
```

and it should resolve appropriately.

Comment: If you're in a browser, it's worth noting that it's not possible to fetch `file://` URLs using AJAX, due to security constraints.

Comment: I've done that but it isn't working and i still don't know why

Comment: Is it possible to paste the actual error?  And are you doing this from JS in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

If your parent and child schemas are in the classpath and in the same place then the best thing to do is to use the custom `resource` URI scheme to load it with an absolute URI:

```
final JsonSchema schema = factory.getJsonSchema("resource:/path/to/parent.json");
```

Then you can reference your child schema using `{ "$ref": "child.json" }` (since JSON References are resolved relatively to the current schema's URI)

Comment: I'm using the module jaySchema and to get the schema i just do something like that "var schema = require('../../contract/entities/operation.json');" then i call that function for validation: "js.validate(req.body, schema)". Is it a good way to do that ??

Comment: Hmmwait... Does this piece of software actually use json-schema-validator at all?

Comment: weah it is based on json-schema-validator